# /proc/meminfo-inactive(file) remain high, and can't be reclaimed by drop_caches

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

Hello everyone,

We use windriver Linux 6.0 in our products (base on yocto 3.10.55).
 And we are faced with a strange problem: inactive(file) in /proc/meminfo remain high. and even we do "echo 3 > /drop/sys/vm/drop_caches", the statistics can't be reclaimed.

```
sh-4.2# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
sh-4.2# free 
             total    used    free  shared  buffers   cached 
Mem:       8000008 7777308  222700       0      196   871328 
-/+ buffers/cache: 6905784 1094224 
Swap:            0       0       0 
sh-4.2# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        8000008 kB 
MemFree:         220988 kB 
Buffers:         288 kB 
Cached:          872912 kB 
SwapCached:      0 kB 
Active:          2145984 kB 
Inactive:        4779720 kB 
Active(anon):    2126188 kB 
Inactive(anon):  804404 kB 
Active(file):    19796 kB 
Inactive(file):  3975316 kB 
Unevictable:     0 kB 
Mlocked:         0 kB 
SwapTotal:       0 kB 
SwapFree:        0 kB 
Dirty:           0 kB 
Writeback:       0 kB 
AnonPages:       2077148 kB 
Mapped:          242972 kB 
Shmem:           853588 kB 
Slab:            145620 kB 
SReclaimable:    121040 kB 
SUnreclaim:      24580 kB 
KernelStack:     10704 kB 
PageTables:      10624 kB 
NFS_Unstable:    0 kB 
Bounce:          0 kB 
WritebackTmp:    0 kB 
CommitLimit:     4000004 kB 
Committed_AS:    4084848 kB 
VmallocTotal:    4294967296 kB 
VmallocUsed:     27604 kB 
VmallocChunk:    4294931084 kB 
HugePages_Total: 0 
HugePages_Free:  0 
HugePages_Rsvd:  0 
HugePages_Surp:  0 
Hugepagesize:    4096 kB
```

The inactive(file) memory can be reduced by malloc() call or copy file to ramdisk(/run or /var/volatile).

But it will affect GDB to attach the running process which used memory large than the free memory. GDB attach will fail. (get can't apply memory issue, then gdb quit: can't attach the process).

As we know Inactive(fils) are free and available. This is a memory that has not been recently used and can be reclaimed for other purposes. But now it caused gdb to fail, or other effects we are not faced yet.

What may cause this issue to appear? And how can I reclaim these memories manually?